# Python: How to explode two columns and set prefix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, prefix, pandas-explode

I have a DataFrame as follows:

```
time         asks                                                                    bids
2022-01-01   [{'price':'0.99', 'size':'32213'}, {'price':'0.98', 'size':'23483'}]    [{'price':'1.0', 'size':'23142'}, {'price':'0.99', 'size':'6436'}]
2022-01-02   [{'price':'0.99', 'size':'33434'}, {'price':'0.98', 'size':'33333'}]    [{'price':'1.0', 'size':'343'}, {'price':'0.99', 'size':'2342'}]

...
2022-01-21   [{'price':'0.98', 'size':'32333'}, {'price':'0.98', 'size':'23663'}]    [{'price':'1.0', 'size':'23412'}]
```

I want to explode the asks and bids columns and set prefixes to get the following:

```
time        asks_price  asks_size   bids_price   bids_size
2022-01-01        0.99      32213          1.0       23142
2022-01-01        0.98      23483         0.99        6436
2022-01-02        0.99      33434          1.0         343
2022-01-02        0.98      33333         0.99        2342
...
2022-01-21        0.98      32333          1.0       23412
2022-01-21        0.98      23663          NaN         NaN
```

Notice how the last row has NaN values under the bids_price and bids_size columns since there are no corresponding values.

How can this be achieved using pandas?

EDIT: Here is a snippet of the data:

```
{'time': {0: '2022-05-07T00:00:00.000000000Z',
  1: '2022-05-07T01:00:00.000000000Z',
  2: '2022-05-07T02:00:00.000000000Z',
  3: '2022-05-07T03:00:00.000000000Z',
  4: '2022-05-07T04:00:00.000000000Z'},
 'asks': {0: [{'price': '0.9999', 'size': '4220492'},
   {'price': '1', 'size': '2556759'},
   {'price': '1.0001', 'size': '941039'},
   {'price': '1.0002', 'size': '458602'},
   {'price': '1.0003', 'size': '257955'},
```

Comment: Can you do `df.head().to_dict()` and post the data here instead of the `print(df)` output?

Comment: The data is too long to be posted as it is orderbook data. But see the edit to see a snippet of the data.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```py
df1 = df.explode(['asks', 'bids'])

df_asks = pd.json_normalize(df1['asks']).rename(columns={'price': 'asks_price', 'size':'asks_size'})
df_bids = pd.json_normalize(df1['bids']).rename(columns={'price': 'bids_price', 'size':'bids_size'})

df_final = df_asks.join(df_bids)
```

`df_final` outputs:

```
|    |   asks_price |   asks_size |   bids_price |   bids_size |
|---:|-------------:|------------:|-------------:|------------:|
|  0 |         0.99 |       32213 |         1    |       23142 |
|  1 |         0.98 |       23483 |         0.99 |        6436 |
|  2 |         0.99 |       33434 |         1    |         343 |
|  3 |         0.98 |       33333 |         0.99 |        2342 |
```

Setup:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"time":[1,2], 
                   "asks":[
                       [{'price':'0.99', 'size':'32213'},
                        {'price':'0.98', 'size':'23483'}],
                       [{'price':'0.99', 'size':'33434'},
                        {'price':'0.98', 'size':'33333'}]], 
                   
                   "bids":[[{'price':'1.0', 'size':'23142'}, 
                            {'price':'0.99', 'size':'6436'}],    
                           [{'price':'1.0', 'size':'343'},
                            {'price':'0.99', 'size':'2342'}] 
                          ]})
```

---

Update:
If you have `time` as index then you can simply add it as last command:

```
df_final.index = df1.index
```

or if you treat `time` as additional column:
[reassigning position of columns is only for convenience]

```
df_final["time"] = df1["time"].reset_index(drop=True)
df_final = df_final[["time", "asks_price", "asks_size", "bids_price", "bids_size" ]]
```

Comment: That works. What about the time column?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.explode()`:

```
df = df.explode(['asks','bids'])

df['asks_price'] = [dict(i)['price'] for i in df['asks']]
df['asks_size'] = [dict(i)['size'] for i in df['asks']]
df['bids_price'] = [dict(i)['price'] for i in df['bids']]
df['bids_size'] = [dict(i)['size'] for i in df['bids']]
```

Comment: For some reason, when I explode the two columns, the time column does not show the hour anymore. Any idea why that may be?

Comment: It still shows the hour on my end. Do you want share your code?

Comment: I'm using exactly your code. I even tried setting the time column to an index, but even after doing that, I still lose the hour after I explode

Comment: I think the reason may be that the asks and bids lists are much longer than the time column so that makes the datetime, time agnostic? I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

One option is to explode, and access the individual columns, using `pd.Series.str`.

I am using @woblob data:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"time":[1,2], 
                   "asks":[
                       [{'price':'0.99', 'size':'32213'},
                        {'price':'0.98', 'size':'23483'}],
                       [{'price':'0.99', 'size':'33434'},
                        {'price':'0.98', 'size':'33333'}]], 
                   
                   "bids":[[{'price':'1.0', 'size':'23142'}, 
                            {'price':'0.99', 'size':'6436'}],    
                           [{'price':'1.0', 'size':'343'},
                            {'price':'0.99', 'size':'2342'}] 
                          ]})

out = df.set_index('time').explode(['asks', 'bids'])
price = out.apply(lambda f: f.str['price']).add_suffix("_price")
size = out.apply(lambda f: f.str["size"]).add_suffix("_size")
pd.concat([price, size],axis=1)
     asks_price bids_price asks_size bids_size
time                                          
1          0.99        1.0     32213     23142
1          0.98       0.99     23483      6436
2          0.99        1.0     33434       343
2          0.98       0.99     33333      2342
```